# QTableView with an editor for all fields

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, qt, qt4

I am trying to modify the `QTableView` to always show all editors. I am ok with the workaround to call `openPersistentEditor()` on all cells.

However I'd like the content of the cells to not be selected and no text cursor for empty fields.

This is what I get:

[image]

And this is what I'd like to have:

[image]

I tried using `clearSelection()` and `clearFocus()` but that does not do the trick. If I click on each cell I get the desired result and I could do the same thing programmatically, but I'd to know if there's a more direct way.

Comment: Maybe instead of using editor use `QAbstractItemView::setIndexWidget`? It should only paint widgets, make them interactive, but shouldn't focus them at all. The only thing is that when you change something in this fielld you will have to apply changed data on your own

Comment: Yeah, I am a bit weary about the second part, because I am not sure what that involves. Would I have to connect the signals from the widget directly in my view and signal the model?

Comment: @KamilKlimek can you give me some pointers on how I should implement a solution with setIndexWidget()?

Comment: Your view should connect on each QLineEdit textChanged/textEdited signal and update model. You should probably create your QLineEdits on rowsInserted signal

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact same issue. I ended up just adjusting the selection color and selection background color on the QLineEdits. You can do it on all QLineEdits or just on a custom QLineEdit by giving each editor an object name and referencing that in the stylesheet.

```
/* applies to all QLineEdits in the application */
QLineEdit { 
  selection-background-color: white;
  selection-color: black
}

/* applies to all QLineEdits with the object name "custom" in the application */
QLineEdit#custom { 
  selection-background-color: white;
  selection-color: black
}
```